# Nodejs export aggregates throws syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, aggregate

I have many smaller modules that make up the complete APIs for a server, each module in it's own file. However, it's fairly annoying to import each module from separate files, thus, I wanted to use export aggregates to simply import them from a single central module.

[As per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), the `export` statement should be able to handle the following aggregation syntax:

```
// Aggregating modules
export * from …; // does not set the default export
export * as name1 from …;
export { name1, name2, …, nameN } from …;
export { import1 as name1, import2 as name2, …, nameN } from …;
export { default } from …;
```

However, I have been unable to use this export syntax; specifically, the `export * as name1 from ...` syntax, which throws a `Unexpected export specifier type` error.

The only form between the above that I am able to use is `export * from ...`, but that isn't particularly useful...

This is how I export APIs in the modules:

```
// user.js - more modules export APIs the same way
export const loginWithEmail = ({ params }) => { /* ... */ }
export const loginWithPhoneNumber = ({ params }) => { /* ... */ }
// ... more exports
```

And this is how I'm exporting these modules in a central module

```
// api.js - resides in the same location as the separate modules
export * as User from "./user";
export * as Vehicle from "./vehicle";
// ... more exports
```

Can someone help me figure out what am I doing wrong ?

The environment is made of VSCode 1.41, NodeJS 13, Expo SDK36, React 16.9, React-Native 0.61, JSX, ES8+ and eslint+babel-eslint.

Comment: The issue is Babel, and this (answered!) question is about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59962828/babel-throws-a-type-error-when-exporting-aggregates/61705000#61705000

It might be worth closing this as a duplicate since I believe they are the same question, but since I provided the answer I will let the community decide.

(I should have answered here since this question is a bit more general and descriptive...  sorry!)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, definitely, that seems to be the issue.